# Image comparison in Python

Tags: python, opencv

I wish to compare difference between two images. I have a solution in hand via 'opencv' to compare whole image. However, I want to improve further to compare specific portion of the images.

Lets say: Image 1 has an rectangular box in it.

[image]

Image 2 has an similar (but not same) rectangular box in it.

[image]

I want to compare only those specific area (text box) NOT the whole image. is there a way to do it? Kindly suggest.

Comment: Use a library like `Pillow` to decode the image and then loop through the pixel's of each image and count the white pixels. If the images only contain 2 rectangular boxes as you show here, then it is the best way. **Edit**: You put `OpenCV` as a tag, but you can still do this.

Answer (score 0):

You could use ImageHash

```
from PIL import Image
import imagehash

hash = imagehash.average_hash(Image.open('test.png'))
otherhash = imagehash.average_hash(Image.open('other.bmp'))

print(hash - otherhash)
```

Comment: What it does? Can you please elaborate if you don't mind? I did execute but apparently not understand the outcome.

Comment: I'm assuming you mean elaborate on what Imagehash does, It basically breaks down the picture and compares distribution and black & gray fractions

heres a full explanation on it 
https://pypi.org/project/ImageHash/